# Netbeans php Model functions autohint

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans, autocomplete

Netbeans isn't reading the phpDoc / autohinting for any functions I have in my Models folder when I'm in a controller that loads said model. So if i'm in the controller ajax.php I don't get autohinting/completeing for `$this->notification->...` even though I have loaded the model notification.php.. I even have @property CI_Model $notification at the top of the page in a comment/phpDoc. Any advice?

Comment: Any suggestions? Is there any other info I can give? I tried a bunch of different things, but nothing has worked, I have autocomplete for other functions, but it just won't give them for the models I load. Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that you show your code

Comment: What code should I show? my phpDoc in the Models that aren't loading? I'm sure they're correct because it works in other functions in the controller, it just won't load the ones for the model. I do @property CI_Model $notification.. but it won't load those functions into the autohelper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to take a look at this post: [CodeIgniter Code Completion with the Netbeans IDE for PHP](http://www.masnun.me/2010/06/16/codeigniter-code-completion-with-the-netbeans-ide-for-php.html)

After that, I add my models to ci_autocomplete.php as this:

`@property Products_Model $Products_Model`

I have this setup currently working on NetBeans IDE 6.8 (Windows)

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: I've tried several tutorials, links and suggestions, but your little extra twist was the magic I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The correct docblock for class properties is

```
class ClassName
{
    /**
     * @var type
     */
    (public|private|protected) $propertyName;
```

So in your case, something like

```
class MyController
{
    /**
     * @var CI_Model
     */
    private $notification;
```